# How to set background-size larger than element itself without wrapper element

Tags: html, css, svg, background, element

Let's say I have some simple SVG icon:

```
<svg class="myclass">
    <use href="#my-icon"/>
</svg>

.myclass {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    &:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        // HOW TO SET BACKGROUND SIZE LARGER THAN ELEMENT SIZE
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
}
```

Is there any native(not hacky) CSS way to apply larger background color size that element itself + apply border radius? Let's say I want that background appear to be 36px; Box shadow doesn't help. Background size as well.
Sure, i know how to do this with wrapper element, but mby i don't need it? Just place your icon and apply background as you want...?

UPDATE: Addendum of [Codepen setup](https://codepen.io/oswee/pen/ZqaKOW)

Comment: Please add some code or snippet. for better understanding what you need and whats happenin...\

Comment: I think you just need padding.  You may have to set `box-sizing: content-box;` depending on if you're using a framework that sets that value.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to manipulate a Svg as a normal html element, and that isn´t the case. Everything you have into a Svg is part of it, so you have 2 options:

1. Edit the Svg itself.
2. Add a wrapper to control Svg´s position on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding padding property will solve your problem.

Or if you want to apply the background color to a icon you can use absolut hight/width and align the icon with the display property (e. g. flex)